# Expression Engine Nest a channel with in a channel

Tags: templates, field, expressionengine, channel

Not even sure if I’m asking the right thing. Here is what I want to do. I have template 1 using channel A. Template 2 using channel B. And I have channel C which is being used in a snippet that is nested in template 1 and 2, between the opening and closing channel tags of channels A and B on both pages. I am trying to have the content contained on Channel C (i have a field group assigned to Channel C) show in both Templates 1 and 2. Not sure if I’m doing it right. Here is an idea of my code which is not working.

Here is a general idea of the code for both templates, omitting all other code:

Template 1

```
{exp:channel:entries channel=“A”}
    {exp:channel:entries channel=“C”}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Template 2

```
{exp:channel:entries channel=“B”}
    {exp:channel:entries channel=“C”}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

When I try to nest {exp:channel:entries channel=“C”} the rest of the content for Channel A and B does not show.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks! G

Answer (score 0):

As you have found you cannot nest in the fashion you describe.  You want to move your channel C stuff into it's own template and then use an embed call in templates 1 and 2 to bring in the channel C data.

You do pay a performance price for embeds tho.